# Проверка пунктуации в предложении (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Она в надежде день ото дня ждёт свою ненаглядную дочку и, казалось бы, вот-вот её увидит, но увы, она так и не дожидается и умирает одинокой старенькой женщиной.*

Особое внимание обратите на «день ото дня» — надо ли обособлять?

Comment: Словарный запас мой расширялся день ото дня;  становится пустее день ото дня; но день ото дня работы становилось всё больше; день ото дня становится всё толковее и интереснее; день ото дня растёт. =========== Выражение «день ото дня ждёт», где отсутствует всякое действие и развитие, будет правильно заменить на ДЕНЬ ЗА ДНЁМ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема грамотности этого предложения не в правописании, а в стиле.

Я бы написала так:

***День за днем в надежде*** ждёт она свою ненаглядную дочку и, казалось бы, вот-вот **увидится** с ней, но, увы, **так и не дождавшись**,  умирает **состарившейся и одинокой**.

Пояснение

1) ***День за днем***: как уже было сказано, этот оборот является более правильным.

2) Два обстоятельства ***день за днем в надежде***  неоднородные, обособление или разделение запятой не требуется.

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно, только перед ***увы*** как перед вводным словом надо поставить ещё одну запятую (при изъятии его смысл не теряется, значит, *но* отделяем). ***День ото дня*** обособлять не нужно.

***Казалось бы*** вводное выражение, поэтому обособляется, *союз **но*** разделяет части сложносочинённого предложения.

[Не назвал бы этого человека неграмотным, кстати. :)]